# Bash function to get all dependencies recursively

Tags: bash, recursion, dependencies

I've got a command that provide me the list of direct dependencies of some package.
Here it is, for example:

```
# get-dep some-random-package
libunistring-1.0
libidn2-2.3.2
glibc-2.35-163
xz-5.2.7
gcc-11.3.0-lib
attr-2.5.1
acl-2.3.1
gmp-with-cxx-stage4-6.2.1
coreutils-9.1
findutils-4.9.0
bash-5.1-p16
pcre-8.45
gnugrep-3.7
zstd-1.5.2
zstd-1.5.2-bin
zlib-1.2.13
openssl-3.0.7
libxml2-2.10.3
bzip2-1.0.8
libarchive-3.6.1-lib
libarchive-3.6.1
gzip-1.12
some-random-package
```

I need to get the **whole** list of dependencies.

by using this `get-dep` command I am trying to write bash function that give me the whole list of dependencies recursivly.
At first glance this function should recursivly pass through each package.
I tried to do next:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

get_the_whole_list_of_dependencies() {
  local list=$(get-dep "${1}")
  local cnt=$(echo "${list}"| wc -l)
  if [ "${cnt}" == 1 ]; then
    echo "${list}"
  else
    for f in ${list}; do
      get_the_whole_list_of_dependencies "${f}"
    done
  fi
}

get_the_whole_list_of_dependencies some-random-package
```

However something goes wrong and the function is turned to be an endless loop.

Does anybody help me with that issue?

Comment: Better use bash arrays than strings, `echo` and `wc -l`, it would be a bit safer. But as for your issue could it be that you have an extra newline at the end of your list of dependencies? You could print the `cnt` count and investigate why it is not equal to 1 when it should be.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for reply. Regarding extra newline, think it is not possible. I used `set +x`, `set -x` to debug and saw that sometimes cnt==1.

Comment: Then you may have some circular dependency... Anyway, printing the whole stuff (counts and lists) shall help understanding where the endless loop comes from.

Comment: When using recursive call, It is needed to pay attention that each sub sequence call is applied on a reduce set of data: I mean that the chain of calls is gonna end.

Thinking about @RenaudPacalet remark on the circular dependencies, maybe it is wise to use an additional bash array variable, global, (a list) containing all the dependencies already analyzed...

The goal is to avoid analyzing twice the same lib

Comment: @Jayjargot this is a great advice (about list of package that have been analyzed). I've just realized that my loop doesn't seem to be endless but it is really really really long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in comments your algorithm is inefficient because it processes the same package as many times as it is encountered. Another bash array could be used to keep track of the already seen packages and avoid this.

Note also that your script prints only the leaves of your dependency tree while you state that you want *the whole list of dependencies recursively*.

If you use a bash array to avoid processing twice the same package, and if your bash supports them, better use an associative array (`local -A seen`) as it makes very easy to check if a package has already been seen.

Example:

```
_get_the_whole_list_of_dependencies() {
  printf '%s\n' "$1"
  local -a list=($(get-dep "$1"))
  seen["$1"]=1
  local -i cnt=${#list[@]}
  if (( cnt > 1 )); then
    for f in "${list[@]}"; do
      if ! [[ -v seen["$f"] ]]; then
        _get_the_whole_list_of_dependencies "$f"
      fi
    done
  fi
}

get_the_whole_list_of_dependencies() {
  local -A seen=()
  _get_the_whole_list_of_dependencies "$1"
}
```

And then:

```
$ get_the_whole_list_of_dependencies zlib
zlib
xz
gettext
gettext-runtime
libiconv
gperf
gettext-tools-libs
libtextstyle
ncurses
```

Comment: Thank you again. Could you tell me please what this line means:
```seen["$1"]=1```

Comment: It sets to `1` the value corresponding to key `"$1"` in associative array `seen`. Associative arrays are arrays which indexes are not numbers but any string. In other programming languages they are sometimes named dictionaries, hashes, maps... Here we use it to "_remember_" that we already encountered package `"$1"`. And we test this with `[[ -v seen["$f"] ]]`.

Comment: Everything works. Thank you so much!!! @renaud-pacalet I promise to vote your answer when I gain enough rating. I tried to vote, but system doesn't accept my voice, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

This is an alternative (and [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean) way to implement a function to print all of the dependencies of a package recursively:

```
function get_all_dependencies
{
    local packages=( "$1" )     # packages whose dependencies need to be found

    local -i first=0 last=0
    local -A is_printed
    local pkg get_dep_output dep
    while (( first <= last )); do
        pkg=${packages[first++]}
        get_dep_output=$(get-dep "$pkg")
        while read -r dep; do
            [[ -z $dep ]] && continue
            [[ -n ${is_printed[$dep]-} ]] && continue
            printf '%s\n' "$dep"
            is_printed[$dep]=_
            packages[++last]=$dep
        done <<<"$get_dep_output"
    done
}
```

Comment: `get_all_dependencies` does not call itself. Didn't you forget to recurse?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet, it doesn't need to use explicit recursion.  It puts packages in the `packages` array instead of calling itself recursively, and it continues until every package in the array has had all of its dependencies checked.  I have tested the function (lightly) with multiple levels of package dependencies.

Comment: But recursively means that is `a` depends on `b`, `b` on `c`, and `c` on `d` you want to catch `d`, not just `a` and `b` or `a` and `b` and `c`. The length of dependency chains is not limited. You must explore the tree from root to leaves, even if the leaves are very far from the root.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet, the code explores the entire tree from root to leaves.  It employs a standard algorithm: using a queue (implemented with the `packages` array) to do a breadth-first traversal.  The algorithm can handle chains of arbitrary length.

Comment: Oh, I see, sorry, I was so obsessed by recursivity that I did not realize the `while (( first <= last ))`. I beg your pardon. This is more iterative than recursive, but it's perfect, and maybe more efficient than a recursive approach, especially with deep trees.